# My nunit tests are not being run from Visual Studio 2013 express

Tags: c#, nunit

In the following code, the tests are not being found in the runner, and I don't know why. Please could some one explain why?

```
[TestFixture]
public class RepositoryTest
{
    [SetUp]
    public void Init()
    {
    }

    [Test]
    public void whenIAskForAllTheLocationsAllTheLocationsAreReturned()
    {
        var repo = new LocationRepository();
        var locations = repo.GetLocationsByName("%");
        Assert.AreEqual(locations.Count(), 8);
        Assert.AreEqual(locations.First().LocationName, "Kipling Road");
    }
}
```

Comment: Besides install NUnit's Test Adapter you can use [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/unit_testing.html) which will automatically detect and run MSTest and NUnit tests.

Comment: @Smith.h.Neil: you should clarify that is not a free component...

Answer (score 1):

Visual studio won't run nunit tests by default, only MSTests. In order to run nunit tests natively from visual studio, install the [NUnit Test Adapter](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=vsTestAdapter&r=2.6.2). Not sure if it is valid for the express edition though.